# How to move or swap elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

The goal is to move an element before its left sibling or after its right sibling.

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>One</li>
</ul>
```

Given only the index of the element, I need to move it to left or right. Say the index is 1 (LI with "Two" as innerText), then I want to move it to left, the output should be:

```
<ul>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>One</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
/**
 * @param siblings {jQuery} List of sibling elements to act upon
 * @param subjectIndex {int} Index of the item to be moved
 * @param objectIndex {int} Index of the item to move subject after
 */
var swapElements = function(siblings, subjectIndex, objectIndex) {
    // Get subject jQuery
    var subject = $(siblings.get(subjectIndex));
    // Get object element
    var object = siblings.get(objectIndex);
    // Insert subject after object
    subject.insertAfter(object);
}
$(function() {
    swapElements($('li'), 0, 1);
});
​
```

​

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/FJt9X/2/

Comment: You missed a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Can you explain what it does?

Comment: Okay, say the index of the element to be moved is 3, where will I put it in your code?

Comment: @dpp I've updated the answer with a function that should be more self-explanatory

Comment: not exactly what I need but it answered the question and helped me to come up with a better idea!

Comment: it is now swap. test it swapElements($('li'), 0, 3); for swap result must be Four,Two,Three,One instead of Two,Three,Four,One

Answer (score 33):

If you need an element to be moved left or right, there are jQuery methods like `next` and `prev` to help you get the next and previous elements where you can apply `insertAfter` or `insertBefore`.

```
//Move right:
$(elementToBeMoved).insertAfter($(elementToBeMoved).next());

//Move left:
$(elementToBeMoved).insertBefore($(elementToBeMoved).prev());
```

Comment: perfect, just what i needed!

Comment: Your brevity here, compared to the other answers, is a work of beauty.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a jquery extension that's easy to use

```
jQuery.fn.swap = function (newIndex) {
    if (!Number.isInteger(newIndex) && !['up', 'down'].includes(newIndex)) {
        throw new Error('Incorrect index format! Allowed formats are: "up", "down" or an index of the sibling to swap with');
    }
    if (Number.isInteger(newIndex)) {
        this.insertBefore(this.siblings()[newIndex]);
    } else {
        if (newIndex === 'up') {
            this.insertBefore($(this.siblings()[this.index() - 1]));
        } else {
            this.insertAfter($(this.siblings()[this.index()]));
        }
    }
}
```

After including above sample this script can be used on jquery objects like:

```
$(this).swap('up');
$(this).swap('down');
$(this).swap(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can swap a list for another

```
$.fn.equals = function(compareTo) {
  if (!compareTo || this.length != compareTo.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    if (this[i] !== compareTo[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

function swap(a, b) {
  a = $(a); b = $(b);

  if (a.length !== b.length) throw "Each list must be of equal length.";

  a.each( function(i,e){ _swap(e,b[i]) } );

  function _swap(a, b) {
    a = $(a); b = $(b);
    if (a.equals(b)) {return;}
    if (a.next().equals(b)) {a.before(b); return;}
    if (b.next().equals(a)) {b.before(a); return;}
    var tmp = $('<span>').hide();
    a.before(tmp);
    b.before(a);
    tmp.replaceWith(b);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/2c7Ltopf/1/

```
var swapElements = function(siblings, subjectIndex, objectIndex) {
    // Get subject jQuery
    var subject = $(siblings.get(subjectIndex));
    // Get object element
    var object = $(siblings.get(objectIndex));
    // Insert subject after object
    subject.insertAfter($(siblings.get(objectIndex)));

    if(objectIndex!==subjectIndex+1)
        $(siblings.get(objectIndex)).insertBefore($(siblings.get(subjectIndex+1)));
}

$(function() {
    swapElements($('li'), 1, 4);
});
```